# After exporting *jar file and replace it in eclipse jar files java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError shows up

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I am stuck on the following issue. I took the **org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring** plugin from the plugins of my eclipse as the source and add the following line.

**DebugPlugin debugPlugin = DebugPlugin.getDefault();**

The DebugPlugin is located in org.eclipse.debug.core so I add this jar to **MANIFEST.MF** under Require-Bundle: in the last line add.
org.eclipse.debug.core;bundle-version="3.18.300"

When I run eclipse from my eclipse plugin everything works fine. I export my **org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_3.12.0.v20210618-1953.jar** and then replace it in the installed eclipse which has a lot of plugins 300+ and one of them has the same name as I exported. When I start eclipse as soon as I try to use my code NoClassDefFoundError immediately throws.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2023-01-30 11:34:48.086
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/debug/core/DebugPlugin
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.resource.RenameResourceWizard$RenameResourceRefactoringConfigurationPage.saveSettings(RenameResourceWizard.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.resource.RenameResourceWizard$RenameResourceRefactoringConfigurationPage.performFinish(RenameResourceWizard.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.performFinish(RefactoringWizard.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardDialog2.okPressed(RefactoringWizardDialog2.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.buttonPressed(Dialog.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5895)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:5126)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4581)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.lambda$0(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringStarter.activate(RefactoringStarter.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.refactoring.rename.RenameSupport.openRenameResourceDialog(RenameSupport.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.refactoring.rename.RenameSupport.openRenameResourceDialog(RenameSupport.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.refactoring.rename.CRefactory.renameResource(CRefactory.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.navigator.CNavigatorRenameResourceAction.run(CNavigatorRenameResourceAction.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.BaseSelectionListenerAction.runWithEvent(BaseSelectionListenerAction.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jface.commands.ActionHandler.execute(ActionHandler.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:97)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.executeCommand(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.press(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.processKeyEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:647)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.filterKeySequenceBindings(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1937)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1524)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1563)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.gtk_key_press_event(Widget.java:924)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.gtk_key_press_event(Control.java:3992)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.gtk_key_press_event(Composite.java:921)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.gtk_key_press_event(Tree.java:2369)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowProc(Widget.java:2408)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:6833)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.windowProc(Tree.java:4237)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:6197)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk3.GTK3.gtk_main_do_event(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.eventProc(Display.java:1565)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk3.GTK3.gtk_main_iteration_do(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4578)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1154)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1045)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1440)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin cannot be found by org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_3.12.0.v20210618-1953
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.generateException(BundleLoader.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 84 more
```

I made a small test project using a class from another jar. I get the same error, but when I set the classpath everything works. I tried to set classpath for eclipse plugins, but it doesn't help.

Thanks in advance for any ideas or help.

Comment: Show us the MANIFEST.MF. No ClassDefFoundError for what class?

Comment: You may well have to start Eclipse with the `-clean` option to get it to rebuild the plug-in dependencies data.

Comment: Thank you a lot @greg-449 you are right. It was very urgent and very important to me. I don't see accept answer option... But it is what help me.